# Modification of the counter with two different buttons vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to edit the update counter from both add and remove button.

Unfortunately, the delete button doesn't update it even if the add button works well as requested.

There is a picture below to show my issue.

here is the code on `codesandbox` which is simpler: `https://hq5lf.csb.app/`

Here is my code:

```html
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-for="option in arrayOption" :key="option.id_option">
           
            <div>
                <div  >
                   
                        <button  @click="deleteOption(option.id_option)" >-</button>
                        <p v-if="option.count == 0">{{ count }}</p>
                        <p v-else>{{ option.count }}</p>
                       <button @click=" addOption(option.id_option)">+</button>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul>
            <li v-for="(optionTests, index) in optionTest" :key="optionTests.selectOption" :nameOptions="optionTests.nameOptions">{{ optionTests.nameOptions }}
                <p> {{optionTests.selectOption}}</p>
                <button @click="removeName(index ,selectOption, count)">Supprimer</button> 
                
            </li> 
        </ul> 
    </div>

</template>

<script>
  data() {
    return {
      arrayOption: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'option1',
          description: 'je suis l option 1 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'option2',
          description: 'je suis l option 2 ajoute moi au panier'
        }
      ],
      count: 0
    }
  },
 methods:{
    deleteOption(id, count){
        localStorage.removeItem(id)
    },
   addOption(id){
        let addArrays = this.arrayOption[id]
        localStorage.setItem("arrayOption",JSON.stringify(addArrays))
    },
    removeName(x, selectOption){
            console.log(selectOption)
            this.optionTest.splice(x,1);
            console.log(x)
            localStorage.removeItem(selectOption)
       },
       
}
</script>
```

This is a picture of my issue:
[image: button remove supprimer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I can see at a glance:

**Key that doesn't exist**

You keep referring to `option.id_option` - but that key doesn't exist in the objects in `arrayOptions`. Do you mean `option.id` instead?

**ID used as index**

This might be intentional, but considering the rest of your code I think this is probably just an error - in your `addOption` method you use the following line:

`let addArrays = this.arrayOption[id]`

It basically means that when you click on the second option, it passes in theory ID 2, but when it afterwards tries to retrieve the index, it's going to get nothing (since the option with ID2 is at the index 1 - arrays start at 0, not at 1.
instead you'd have to search for the id like this:

```
 addOption(id){
        let addArrays = array.find(el=>el.id===id)
        localStorage.setItem("arrayOption",JSON.stringify(addArrays))
    },
```

Comment: thank you @thomas Kuhlmann , I think I reproduced the code incorrectly, I created a code to explain my problem. In the original table it is id_option, the counter goes to zero when I click on deleteOption, but not when I click on removename

Comment: Then I would recommend reproducing the error in i.e. https://codesandbox.io/ - it's pretty much impossible to help you if your post doesn't even show the -actual- problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help @thomas Kuhlmann , I created a model on codesendbox : https://hq5lf.csb.app/ , the problem is when I click on the delete button which is in the todo list part, I cannot reset the option counter to zero

Comment: @tony is this what you are looking for? http://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-goldstine-s3e8e?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thank you very very much @Thomas Kuhlmann that's exactly what I was looking for I spent 4 days trying several things but I am a novice

Comment: @tony no problem, glad I could help. Just as a general tip - try to avoid maintaining counters manually, it's an extra effort to keep them in sync. Just use computed properties and/or filters like I did -> ```optionTest.filter((el) => el.id === option.id).length }}```

Comment: very good @Thomas Kuhlmann , thanks for the advice. I will work a lot more on the filters and the properties to calculate

Answer (score 0):

your `count` is outside the object and you are calling it as `option.count` in `v-for` loop

Remove your mismatch scenario.

Comment: is it possible to recover option.count ?

Comment: on `count` what you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry it's me who made a mistake, it is well in the object.

Comment: I want to be able to update the counter with the delete button which is in the tudo list

Comment: in `deleteoption` function, there are 2 parameters and but on call you are sending 1 parameter

Comment: when i try to add removename i can't modify the counter or delete the option in the tudo list